# Use loop with multiple array

Tags: arrays, windows, loops, batch-file

I try to create a simple batch file to install Windows CRM.
To do it i created 2 arrays which contains URI and name of the downloaded files.

Now, I want to iterate into theses array to download my files.
I proceed this way :

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set name=(
SSCERuntime-ENU-x86.msi
SSCERuntime-ENU-x64.msi
msoidcli_64.msi
wllogin_64.msi
ReportViewer.exe
CRM2011-Client-FRA-i386.exe
)

set link=(
"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=147327"
"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=147326"
"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=221500"
"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=194722" 
"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=193386&clcid=0x409"
)

for %%G in %name% do echo %%G = !%%G!

SET i = 1
(for %%a in (%name%) do (
  if exist \\srv-dc22\netlogon\CRM\%%G (
  echo %%G : Already donwnloaded
)else (
  echo Downloading %%G
  powershell -command "& { iwr %link[i]% -OutFile %%G }"
  SET /A i+=1
  )
 )
)
```

But even if i success to get the value for "name" , i do not success to iterate my "link" array.

What's wrong?

Comment: You need to append _space_ + `^` to every line in your multi-line `set` commands (except after `)`) to tell the command interpreter that the command line is continued; otherwise every line is interpreted as a separate command; the _space_ serves as delimiter (needed by `for` later); if any of the items contain white-spaces or special characters, enclose each in `""`; expand the `for` variable using `~` like `%%~a` to remove the `""` afterwards...

Comment: I tried what you gave to me , but it seems not functionnal. i still not have the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several points involved in your question...

In Batch files there is NOT a *predefined support* for arrays. You may still *emulate* the array management in Batch files making good use of the fact that the names of Batch variables may include almost any special character. For example `set var=123` is *the same* (from Batch file processing point of view) than `set array[1]=123`. This way, *is up to you* to successfully *emulate* the array management in Batch files. You may read further details on this point at: [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the *list* named "name"
set name=SSCERuntime-ENU-x86.msi SSCERuntime-ENU-x64.msi msoidcli_64.msi wllogin_64.msi ReportViewer.exe CRM2011-Client-FRA-i386.exe

rem Define the *array* named "link"
set "link[1]=http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=147327"
set "link[2]=http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=147326"
set "link[3]=http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=221500"
set "link[4]=http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=194722" 
set "link[5]=http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=193386&clcid=0x409"

for %%G in (%name%) do echo %%G

SET i=1
for %%G in (%name%) do (
   if exist \\srv-dc22\netlogon\CRM\%%G (
      echo %%G : Already donwnloaded
   ) else (
      echo Downloading %%G
      for %%i in (!i!) do powershell -command "& { iwr !link[%%i]! -OutFile %%G }"
      SET /A i+=1
   )
)
```

In previous code, the definition of the "link" array could be done in a `for` command in a simpler (and less ugly) way; however, the inclusion of the `?` special character in the values avoids to use they as string literals in a `for`.